# Watir - get image without any property

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have such structure:

```
<div id="recaptcha_image" style="width: 300px; height: 57px;">
  <img style="display:block;" alt="Проверка по слову reCAPTCHA" height="57" width="300" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VusSUxF0IYURRcVTVTjJJnUk92j-hXYsuwqvu0m5tvKFzAnwvrHlz-j_Gfqg-sUrHLj3D2DrUYNNg4uvr2BNgZqlK5vpJUJVYkkWo36I4RRmRGkYZru5kBYhzPCCn49KlH6wW_iLw6vIzv7vnhpu6ndqxb-9SkIRrVYyBwN39kg18Lov7Hc">
</div>
```

How can I, using watir, save this image (it is recaptcha)?
Because I can't access it via name, id, or class.... only via parent id, but how?

Like this:

```
@browsers.image(:id=> '//recaptcha_image').save("cap.jpg")
```

So how to access image with no properties, and dynamic path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the parent, you can access the parent and then get the first image (since there is only one image in the div tag). So you can get the image element by:

```
@browsers.div(:id => 'recaptcha_image').image
```

And to save the image:

```
@browsers.div(:id => 'recaptcha_image').image.save("cap.jpg")
```

Comment: note, that watir-webdriver has no save method... but this is another question

Comment: maybe you know how to save?

Comment: Ah sorry. I saw `save` in the Watir-Webdriver rdoc, so I assumed incorrectly that it was implemented. The only workaround I know is to use something like the `open-uri` gem to access the image's src directly.